# Scypy: Wilcoxon test: Compare distribution with a single value

Tags: python, statistics

I was applying the t-student test in order to evaluate whether or not a value was belonging to a given sample. Since I cannot assume normality, now I want to apply the `Wilcoxon` test from `scypy`.

Is it possible to compare a sample with a single value?

If I do:
`stats.wilcoxon(sample_array , single_value)`

The code argues that the two arrays don't have the same length. 
I found in a forum that the one sample counterpart for the t-student using `wilcoxon` would be:

`stats.wilcoxon(sample_array - single_value)`

Is it correct? If not, do you know any alternative in order to perform a non parametric test in order to evaluate if a given value belongs or not to a sample distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use wilcoxon for that. Those are to compare distributions.

You can't know whether or not a value may belong to a given sample. If your sample is large enough you can say that the probability of that happening is `sum(sample_array>single_value)/len(sample_array)` (or `<` for the other extreme).

You can compare the value to the MEAN or the MEDIAN of the population using bootstrapping:

```
import scikits.bootstrap as bootstrap
CIs = bootstrap.ci(sample_array, statfunction=np.mean,n_samples=100000)  
print(CIs)
```

If the value is within the CIs, then you can't reject that your value is the real mean (or median).

Comment: Thanks @Javier.. But, for example.. the t-student test allows you to say, of course with a significance level.. how likely is that your given value belongs or not to the distribution you are testing against.. With the bootstrapping I cannot really answer the same type of question.. so i am looking for a non parametric alternative to the t-test.. which in many cases is supposed to be the wilcoxon test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test

Comment: No it doesn't.  It tells you the same than bootstrapping, if a value is significantly different than the mean. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#One-sample_t-test